# How to format a dictionary of lists as a table in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
dic = {'S00:D58': 1, 'M23:Q14': 1, 'S43:H52': 84, 
       'S43:H53': 2, 'S43:H50': 5, 'S43:H57': 1, 'M87:E11': 10}
```

I want to print it out as table  with 3 columns like:

```
S00         D58          1    
M23         Q14          1   
S43         H52          84   
S43         H53          2   
S43         H50          5   
S43         H57          1   
M87         E11          10
```

Is there a simple way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ljust` to do that:

```
for k,v in dic.items():
    a,b = k.split(':')
    print a.ljust(30), b.ljust(30), v
```

Will print this:

```
S00                            D58                            1
M23                            Q14                            1
S43                            H52                            84
S43                            H53                            2
S43                            H50                            5
S43                            H57                            1
M87                            E11                            10
```

From the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ljust):

> These functions respectively left-justify, right-justify and center a
>   string in a field of given width. They return a **string that is at
>   least width characters wide**, created by padding the string s with the
>   character fillchar (default is a space) until the given width on the
>   right, left or both sides. The string is never truncated.

Note that you can also use [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) to get the same effect:

```
print '{:<30s}{:<30s}{}'.format(a, b, v)
```

Comment: I have a quick question! do u know how to sort with Tab Delimiter?

Comment: You can use `collections.OrderedDict(sorted(dic.items()))` to sort you dict by key, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

you could also use the the string formatting method [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
for k, v in dic.items():
    a, b = k.split(':')
    print '{:30s}{:30s}{}'.format(a, b, v)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> dic = {'S00:D58': 1, 'M23:Q14': 1, 'S43:H52': 84, 
       'S43:H53': 2, 'S43:H50': 5, 'S43:H57': 1, 'M87:E11': 10}
>>>
>>> output = '\n'.join(['{:<10} {:<10} {:<10}'.format(*k.split(':'), dic[k]) for k in dic])
>>> print(output)
S43        H52        84        
S43        H53        2         
S00        D58        1         
S43        H57        1         
M87        E11        10        
S43        H50        5         
M23        Q14        1
```